# suddenly cant install apk on my android device

Tags: android, apk

I use to test and create apk (release / debug) and test it on my android device.
I did delete the app before installing new versions.

after awhile, when I uninstall it from the device and try to install new apk it gives me the error:

```
An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed
```

I cant find the app on my android device and cant install any other version or something.

Im still on testing stage and not publishing to store so I assume theres no need to change the version.

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the same app on the device signed with a different key.  This can be either because you purposely changed keys (such as trying a release key), or because your debug key expired and a new one was generated (happens every year), or because you built on a different machine with a different key.  To fix this, uninstall the old version.  To keep it fixed, create a single debug key and share it between all programmers/machines you're compiling on.

Comment: indeed I changed a PC but created a new key for that. So ill try to get that key from there.
and the problem is I already uninstall the app from my device and cant find it there (I use to upload it to drive and download on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
I went to other method- connected the device through adb and tried to install the apk. therefore I got a better output for the error message:

```
adb -s 8a1213bf install ...app-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install 
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Scanning Failed.: Can't install because provider name com.marianhello.app.mauron85.bgloc.provider (in package com.yapp) is already used by com.other app??]
```

There was an old app I published to google store and downloaded from there.
Ofcourse I deleted that app and it works!!

That is weird. someone has explanation?

(Thanks to the one before who his post somewhy deleted - it gave me the curious to connect my device via adb to force install the apk).